# change height of div to browser window height so long a the browser height is greater than x

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm hoping someone will be able to explain what i am doing wrong here:

```
 var winHeight = $(window).height(),
 minHeight = 900,
 Height = 900;

 $(document).ready(function () {

 if (winHeight < MinHeight) {
     Height = minHeight;
 } else {
     Height = winHeight;
 }
 $('div.page').css('height', winHeight + 'px');
});


 $(window).resize(function () {
 if (winHeight < MinHeight) {
     Height = minHeight;
 } else {
     Height = winHeight;
 }
 $('div.page').css('height', winHeight + 'px');

});
```

On my page I have multiple divs with the class "page".
I'm trying make the height of these the size of the browser window, unless the browser window is less than 900, then I want them to be 900px tall.

I'm guessing its a syntax issue. Especially since I'm brand new to jquery and javascript ( I only started using it today).

Comment: what happens? what is "it"?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `$(window).height()` on the resize event, so you can respond to the current window size. You can go with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Call the method one time
    updateWindowSize();
    //Subscribe the method to future resize events
    $(window).resize(updateWindowSize);

    //updateWindowSize inside a closure to hide 'minHeight'
     var updateWindowSize = (function(){
        var minHeight = 900;

        //Actual updateWindowSize function
        return function(){
            var winHeight = $(window).height();
            var newHeight = winHeight < minHeight ? minHeight : winHeight;
            $('div.page').height(newHeight);
        }
     })();
});
```

Comment: thanks after trying you answer for some reason it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: also i noticed the line `var winHeight = $(window).height();;` had 2 `;` but i dont think that would make a difference

Comment: Could you post your HTML to try it out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of winHeight is never changed when window resizes. And I wonder where the variable "Height" is used ?

The code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $(window).resize(function () {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    minHeight = 900,
    Height = 900;
    if (winHeight < minHeight) {
       Height = minHeight;
    } else {
       Height = winHeight;
    }

    $('div.page').height(Height);
  });
});
```

Make sense?

Comment: out of curiosity with jquery and functions do variables need to be declared in the function or can they be included outside of the function?

Comment: This's not jQuery specific question, but a basic Javascript stuff. I think you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Comment: Check out my answer to clarify how variable scope can be used here

Comment: thanks after trying you answer for some reason it doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: if it helps my html code is essentially ` <div class="page" style="background-color:#F63;">&nbsp;</div><div class="page" style="background-color:#0F0;">&nbsp;</div>
  `

Comment: It's not surprised :) Because I've not tested the code, it's just a suggestion in a way it should be. You should debug yourself to find the problem.

Comment: I can see there are two <div> with class 'page'. Do you any external styles related to 'height' for this class? Because it can override the height we set in code.

Comment: nope the height of the divs has never been declared - thanks for all you help